# Any other way to optimize this?

Tags: java, bukkit, repeat

So my code is:

```
public void checkArmor() {
    Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(this, new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                if (p.getInventory().getBoots().getType() == Material.CHAINMAIL_BOOTS
                        && p.getInventory().getLeggings().getType() == Material.CHAINMAIL_LEGGINGS
                        && p.getInventory().getChestplate().getType() == Material.CHAINMAIL_CHESTPLATE
                        && p.getInventory().getHelmet().getType() == Material.CHAINMAIL_HELMET) {
                    p.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.FAST_DIGGING, 20, 0));
                    p.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.FIRE_RESISTANCE, 20, 1));
                    p.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.DAMAGE_RESISTANCE, 20, 0));
                }
                if (p.getInventory().getBoots().getType() == Material.LEATHER_BOOTS
                        && p.getInventory().getLeggings().getType() == Material.LEATHER_LEGGINGS
                        && p.getInventory().getChestplate().getType() == Material.LEATHER_CHESTPLATE
                        && p.getInventory().getHelmet().getType() == Material.LEATHER_HELMET) {
                    p.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.SPEED, 20, 1));
                    p.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.JUMP, 20, 1));
                    p.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.INCREASE_DAMAGE, 20, 1));
                }
                if (p.getInventory().getBoots().getType() == Material.IRON_BOOTS
                        && p.getInventory().getLeggings().getType() == Material.IRON_LEGGINGS
                        && p.getInventory().getChestplate().getType() == Material.IRON_CHESTPLATE
                        && p.getInventory().getHelmet().getType() == Material.IRON_HELMET) {
                    p.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.REGENERATION, 20, 0));
                    p.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.SLOW, 20, 1));
                    p.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.HEALTH_BOOST, 20, 1));
                }
                if (p.getInventory().getBoots().getType() == Material.GOLD_BOOTS
                        && p.getInventory().getLeggings().getType() == Material.GOLD_LEGGINGS
                        && p.getInventory().getChestplate().getType() == Material.GOLD_CHESTPLATE
                        && p.getInventory().getHelmet().getType() == Material.GOLD_HELMET) {
                    p.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.SATURATION, 20, 2));
                    p.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.NIGHT_VISION, 140, 0));
                    p.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.FAST_DIGGING, 20, 1));
                    p.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.GLOWING, 20, 1));
                }
            }
        }
    }, 0, 10);
}
```

I'd like to know if there's any more way to optimize this? I've asked around in bukkit and spigot, but no one really gave me any tips, so I've come here.
Also, before it reapplies the effect it lets the potion effect run out first, instead of reapplying it every half second.

Comment: For questions about optimising code that already works, you might want to ask on [codereview.se](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). However, I encourage you to read [this](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the same methods over and over again. Why not call them only once and assign the results to some variable, like

```
leggingsType = p.getInventory().getLeggings().getType();
```

I don't really think that this makes a huge performance difference but it will make the code more readable.